# I am getting the wrong client IP address

Tags: asp.net

I am running an ASP.NET application. The web server is located on the same system. In the code behind I just want to get the IP address of the requesting client.  I am using this code:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

But I am getting a wrong address: `127.0.0.1`.  My system IP address is `198.162.0.27`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the right one. `127.0.0.1` is the loopback IP address, which is mapped in your `hosts` file to localhost.

If you connect from a remote computer, you will get the remote computers network address.

Comment: ok, one moment of my ego-weakness - you have right on this part. From the other hand stackOverflow is not a place that some one with questions learn to programming, and because vibin say that is software engineer, is somthing like that:a patient go to a doctor, doctor I have  headache, and doctor ask on stackdoctockrs overflow, what to do on headache, then the first reaction is, who make you doctor ? Do you think that programmers don responsible for what they programming ? If they do not know, is better learn first, and here they not learn.

Comment: @Aristos - StackOverflow is also for people who are just learning to program. I agree that as a beginner one should not call themselves a software engineer, but this is not reason to not answer people.

Comment: as I say, a moment of my weakness... yes they must get an answer what ever the question is.