# Ip address of the client machine

Tags: asp.net, ip-address

Please let me know how to get the client IP address,

I have tried all of the below things , but I am getting the same output: 127.0.0.1

```
string strClientIP;
strClientIP = Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();

string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
string clientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();

string ipaddress = string.Empty ;
ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (ipaddress == "" || ipaddress == null)
    ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

How can I get the correct IP?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612591/i-am-getting-the-wrong-client-ip-address

Comment: I had the same issue. I resolved it with this blog post: [How to get IP Address of a client system using ASP.net](http://dotnetstock.com/technical/how-to-get-ip-address-of-a-client-system-using-asp-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track with `REMOTE_ADDR`, but it might not work if you are accessing the site locally, it will show local host.

`REMOTE_ADDR` is the header that contains the clients ip address you should check that first.

You should also check to for the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED` header in case you're visitor is going through a proxy.  Be aware that `HTTP_X_FORWARDED` is an array that can contain multiple comma separated values depending on the number of proxies.

Here is a small c# snippet that shows determining the client's ip:

```
 string clientIp = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
 if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIp) ) {
  string[] forwardedIps = clientIp.Split( new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
  clientIp = forwardedIps[forwardedIps.Length - 1];
 } else {
  clientIp = context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 }
```

Comment: Also be aware that System.Net.Dns.GetHostName will get the address of the local machine that you are running on!

Comment: Does that mean that after deploying to the server this code wil work fine ?

 string ipaddress = string.Empty ;
    ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (ipaddress == "" || ipaddress == null)
        ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

Comment: Not necessarily, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can be a single ip address or an array of ip address, you may need to take that into account.  Otherwise I think it should work, you can always try exposing the code on your local machine via IIS, then connecting through a different computer to see what ip it reports.  You might also want to consider `String.IsNullOrEmpty( ... ) ` instead of `(ipaddr = "" || ipaddr == null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect via the localhost address, then your client address will also report as localhost (as it will route through the loopback adapter)